# Mule Validation Module XSD failure when running as war in tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, mule, mule-component

When I try to run mule as a war in tomcat 7 I am getting following error

```
    org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from mule-config.xml;
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain handledExtensions manager (org.mule.api.lifecycle.
    InitialisationException)
            at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
            at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
            at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$2.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:108)
            at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222)
            at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:103)
            at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.createMuleContext(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:165)
            at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:94)
            at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:70)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from mule-config.xml; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain handledExtensions manager
            at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:112)
            at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172)
            at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95)
            at org.mule.config.builders.WebappMuleXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(WebappMuleXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:79)
            at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
            ... 16 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from 
    mule-config.xml; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain handledExtensions manager
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:191)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
            at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108)
            at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104)
            ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain handledExtensions manager
            at org.mule.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:38)
            at org.mule.module.extension.internal.config.ExtensionsNamespaceHandler.init(ExtensionsNamespaceHandler.java:64)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:85)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:140)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:140)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:56)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
            ... 29 more

    org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from mule-config.xml;
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain handledExtensions manager (org.mule.api.lifecycle.
    InitialisationException)
            at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
            at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
            at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$2.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:108)
            at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222)
            at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:103)
            at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.createMuleContext(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:165)
            at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:94)
            at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:70)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from mu
    le-config.xml; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain handledExtensions manager
            at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:112)
            at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172)
            at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95)
            at org.mule.config.builders.WebappMuleXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(WebappMuleXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:79)
            at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
            ... 16 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document fro
    m mule-config.xml; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain handledExtensions m
    anager
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:191)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
            at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108)
            at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104)
            ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain handledExtensions manager
            at org.mule.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:38)
            at org.mule.module.extension.internal.config.ExtensionsNamespaceHandler.init(ExtensionsNamespaceHandler.java:64)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:85)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:140)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:140)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180)
            at org.mule.config.spring.MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:56)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
            ... 29 more
```

And when I remove validations like below  I have used then this error will not be thrown

e.g.

```html
<validation:is-true  expression="#[payload != null" 
          message="Null Payload returned" />
```

And there's a reported bug in mule 3.7 for this https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8487 which marked as fix for a different scenario ("stand alone execution").

I am using mule 3.7.0 and running on tomcat 7

Questions:

1. If it's fixed what are the jar I need to change in pom.xml
   [

   ```
           <groupId>org.mule.extensions</groupId>
           <artifactId>mule-extensions-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0-alpha-1</version>
   ```

Since it's mentioned it's Extensions API I tried it buy it didn't work out

2. Or how should approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your POM and test.

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule/mule-extensions -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
   <artifactId>mule-extensions</artifactId>
   <version>3.7.0</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This POM provides all dependencies needed for mule-extension support. Since the community can't test your situation hands-on, try this. The POM dependency snippet you referred above is included with this POM, but also many others related to Mule extensions. Try this and please note the issue if it works.

Comment: I have tried, put please find what I have found so far in my investigation https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/43720/mule-validation-module-xsd-failure-when-running-as.html

Comment: I tend to agree with Mariano. You're trying to stretch the limits of running Mule in a Tomcat container. I would focus my efforts on running Mule standalone and not use Tomcat. If you're only doing this to be consistent with deployments, I think it would be worth the effort to stand up an instance of Mule in isolation specifically for your Mule application deployments. If anyone else agrees with me, please 1+ vote this answer to the original poster.

Comment: What i found was mule 3.7.0 Standalone doesn't add Namespace handler for Validation module when it runs as webapp with tomcat. Because similar issue has been fixed for standalone earlier but not applied to webapp now I have download the mule 3.7.0 source code and doing the fix in the source.